# Polidea's iOS Class Guard successful, but can't tell the difference

Tags: ios, objective-c, static-libraries, obfuscation

I'm developing a static library and used Polidea's iOS Class Guard to obfuscate my static library. I followed the steps to download obfuscate_project in my project's root path, changed the required names inside, and finally run bash obfuscate_project in my terminal. I got a message saying that my build succeeded, but I couldn't find my symbols.h file. I also noticed that a build folder was generated. My question is, did obfuscation actually happen? If so, how do I check? Is the obfuscated project inside my build folder?

Comment: Why are you obfuscating? If you don't know how to check whether your product is obfuscated or not you probably don't need to be obfuscating anything...

Comment: @dcow It's a requirement to add a layer of protection against tools like class-dump. I don't think answering my question with a question is of much help...

Comment: That's why I commented, not posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [PPiOS-Rename](https://github.com/preemptive/PPiOS-Rename) (a fork of iOS Class Guard) [explains how to do it](https://github.com/preemptive/PPiOS-Rename#verifying-obfuscation):

> To verify that your app has been obfuscated, use the `nm` utility, which is included in the Xcode Developer Tools. Run:
>
> nm path/to/your/binary | less
>
> This will show the symbols from your app. If you do this with an unobfuscated build, you will see the orginal symbols. If you do this with an obfuscated build, you will see obfuscated symbols.
>
> Note that `nm` will not work properly after stripping symbols from your binary. You can use the `otool` utility if you need to check for the Objective-C symbols after stripping.
>
> `otool` will show unneeded information, but it can be filtered using `grep` and `awk` to only show symbols:
>
> ```
> otool -o /path/to/your/binary | grep 'name 0x' | awk '{print $3}' | sort | uniq
> ```

Comment: it's good practice to disclose your connection to a given product/company (in this case [PreEmptive Solutions](https://www.preemptive.com/products/))

Answer (score 0):

Hey，don't know you have fixed this issue or not.I just met the same problem as yours today，and I found the cause accidentally ，all that because DerivedData file,this file expected to locate at `/Users/'username'/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` by default,but in my project the DerivedData file is located at the root path of the project,and all my projects are the same. I guess this code`while read app`in obfuscate_project 78 line is looking for app in DerivedData file through the default path,obviously it won't be found,so other code after this line isn't executed.

Follow these steps to change DerivedData file path: Xcode->Preferences->Locations, select 'Derived Data' option 'Default',and choose 'Unique' in 'Advanced',then delete DerivedData file in project finder，compile project，now run `bash obfuscate_project`should be successful.